# Unable to solve Undefined offset error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to export an excel file excdemo.xlsx to mysql database using php.
I get an undefined offset error.What could be the reason

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("db2017",$link);


$source = fopen('excdemo.xlsx', 'r') or die("Problem open file");
    while (($data = fgetcsv($source, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $name = $data[0];
        $lname = $data[1];
        $phone = $data[2];
        $email = $data[3];
        $address = $data[4];
        $high = $data[5];


 mysql_query("INSERT INTO excel(fname,lname,phone,email,address,high) VALUES ('".$name."','".$lname."','".$phone."','".$email."','".$address."','".$high."') ");
    }
    fclose($source);
}
```

Error :

> Undefined offset: 4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Exam\main.php 
>   Please omit my use of mysql instead of mysqli_

Comment: Please update your question with a `var_dump()` of the `$data`. It clearly has something to do with the `$data`;

Comment: `fgetcsv` ??!! that's an excel file not a csv, if you want to read xlsx in php take a look at [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. While creating an excel sheet we need to set the file type to **CSV(MS-DOS)** as we use are using the `fgetcsv()` function.!